# What does the word 'circumambiate' mean?

Tags: meaning

Examples:

- Every sort of difficulty is put in our way, and it is up to us to find means to jump over the rolling barrel and **circumambiate** the vagrant cow in our path.
- ... fill the million flats that **circumambiate** the charismatic centre of the great city ...
- They have "squandered" here, and if we scatter too, and **circumambiate** around, we will be apt to strike the trail again where they come together.

What is the definition of this word?

Comment: I can't find this in any on-line source.

Comment: Sounds like a conflation of _circumambient_ (“Going or extending round; surrounding, encompassing, environing”, OED) and _circumambulate_ (“To walk round about”, OED).

Comment: I'm going to *trust* that you tried looking this up in a dictionary (don't make me regret it), and break out the morphology for you: *circum*- (as in *circumscribe*) and -*ambiate* (almost certainly as in *amble* or *somnambulance*). Can you work it out from there?

Comment: @Dan It’s not in the OED, M-W, or ODO. The first and third examples look like they are simply supposed to be _circumambulate_ (which is indeed the same as _amble_, _ambulance_, etc.); the second one looks like a newly-derived verb from the adjectival _circumambient_.

Comment: Since it's apparently nowhere, where did this word come from?

Comment: Please add links to your examples.

Answer (score 3):

The Latin verb

> circumambire

means to 'go around'. **Circumambiate** is not a commonly used verb in English, however the adjective **circumambient** meaning 'surrounding' does have enough use to appear in dictionaries.

The following text from http://www.hyponoesis.org/Essays/Essay/e033 gives an interesting comparison of 3 Latin verbs with *circum-* as their prefix where the English equivalents are adverbs:

> This process of approximation to the target pattern proceeds
>   circumstantially (Lat. circum-stare = stand around), circumambiently
>   (Lat. circum-ambire = to go around) or circumferentially (Lat.
>   cirum-ferre = carry around), that is from all sides, surrounding the
>   target pattern, encircling it more and more, until having become
>   united with the core of the target pattern

Note that of the 3 English adjectives in the passage above, **circumstantiate** exists as a verb of **circumstantial**.